# How to use mongoose model inside a JavaScript class

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a server file and mongoose model file. as given below.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    var path = require('path');
    var mongoosedb = require('mongoose')
    var {userModel} = require('./users/user');

    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyparser.json());

    app.get('/getuser',(req,res)=>{
      userModel.find().then((user)=>{
        res.send({status:1,res:user})
      }).cathc((error)=>{
       res.send({status:0,res:'Some error occurred on server'})
      })
    })
   app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server is running on port 3000');
   })
```

Here I am fetching data using mongoose object. Everything is running perfectly. But I want to do the same thing using Class. How can I use {usermodel} in a class file so that I can use separate functions for fetching ,updating deleting data inside mongodb.

Example:
Suppose I have a class file name is Test

```
var {userModel} = require('./users/user');
class Test{

 getAllUser(){

   return this.userModel.find().then((allusers)=>{
                return allusers
            }).catch((error)=>{
                return 'Some error found';
            })
  }

 deleteUser(user_id){
   return delete_response
 }
 insertUser(user_id){
   return insert_response
 }
}
```

I know above syntax is not correct. But that is what I want.

Thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from using the model in a class? You're doing it right other than the `this.userModel.find()` when it should be `userModel.find()`

Comment: Thanks  Matthew Weeks. You got the exact issue. I was getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` when I was using `this.userModel.find()`
You save my night. how I can be so stupid.